# Not able to set meta data on a resque-status hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-meta

As per the resque-status home page on GitHub I should be able to pass back data from a job. For some reason this does not seem to be working for me. If anyone else has encountered this problem and worked around it I would like to know how.

I am using resque-status with JRuby 1.6.5 in a Rails 3.2.3 application.

---

Passing back data from the job

You may want to save data from inside the job to access it from outside the job.

A common use-case is web-triggered jobs that create files, later available for download by the user.

A Status is actually just a hash, so inside a job you can do:

status['filename'] = '/myfilename'
Also, all the status setting methods take any number of hash arguments. So you could do:

complete('filename' => '/myfilename')

Comment: Tried request-meta and that does the job for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently such functionality is not implemented, as read on
https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status/issues/66

we've found a work around using the function set_status to add the required data to the status hash:

```
set_status({"my variable" => "my value" })
```

hope this helps!